# Raspberry Pi 2 Model B and External 2.5 USB3.0 HDD

Tags: raspbian, hard-drive

As per the title, I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B and I thought it would be nice to have some extra space so I plugged my external HDD.

Here's the specs:

The HDD: [HGST 0S03560 1TB 2.5 inch Touro Mobile Pro External Hard Drive](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00AK5KJ8S?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00)

The power supply: [CSL - microUSB Netzteil / Ladegerät (2100mA / 1000mA) | 5V DC USB](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B017NHIC6G?psc=1&redirect=true&ref_=oh_aui_detailpage_o00_s00)

The OS: Raspbian

I would like to mention, that the Raspberry Pi works marvelously, powering the HDD is the only problem.

The HDD works well, on both 3.0 and 2.0 USB ports, on my laptop, desktop, TV, PS3, Wii.

Whilst on the Raspberry Pi, it **spins for a few moments then stops**, it alternates like this for as long as it's connected.

Comment: Are you aware of [this issue](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/32873/5538), i.e., do you have `max_usb_current=1` in `config.txt`?

Answer (score 1):

You really want to power the Hard Drive from a powered USB HUB - what are the LEDs on the Pi-2 doing? I suspect you will find the one that indicates the Power is OK is telling you it is NOT.

Comment: I can't exactly see the leds, since the Raspberry Pi 2 is in a case. I'll try opening it tomorrow. I'll also try your advice with the powered USB HUB.

Comment: On the Pi2 low power is also indicated by a rainbow-coloured square in the top-right corner of the screen - and a red square indicates overheating - power down ASAP in that case.

Comment: It never overheated before

Comment: It probably won't normally but some people do overclock/core-voltage change them (which can permanently set the "warrenty bit").  Oh, and welcome to the Stack Exchange communities (and this Raspberry flavoured corner of it)!

Comment: Thank you for the welcoming, but I had an account here since a few months ago. I never overclocked it, I only set it to work on high(1000MHz)

Comment: That's overclocked, albeit within an officially sanctioned range.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the aforementioned answers may be easier, but what could work would be to splice a USB cord to only have the power cables connected to the male head and then have that plugged into a proper power supply. Or if you wanted to be boring you could just buy a USB "Y" cord.

Comment: I believe you can get ready made power-only Usb leads if that is what you mean?

Comment: Yes. I mean it's relatively easy to make your own, but you'd need a "Y-shaped" USB cable where one of the heads only carries power