# Keyboard and mouse stops working after connecting usb hard drive

Tags: usb, hard-drive, usb-power, keyboard, mouse

The wireless USB keyboard stops working when I connect a USB hard drive. I also tried to connect a non wireless USB mouse together with the USB disk and the mouse stopped working.

I'm running raspbian as OS. The disk was first formated as ntfs, but I have also tried changing the file system to ext4.

The USB disk works well on my Ubuntu laptop.

So is this power related or can something else cause the problem? I'm using the power adapter from an HTC mobile phone.

Comment: Which model of pi?

Comment: Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

Comment: Try adding `max_usb_current=1` to `/boot/config.txt` then reboot (see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/32873/5538).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like most other issues with the Raspberry Pi, this is most likely a power issue.

Make sure you are using a **short** *and* **thick** USB cable. And a supply that provides at least `5V` at `1A`, but I highly recommend using a `5V` at `1.2A` or `2A` supply.

**EDIT:**

As Steve said, a powered USB hub is also a good idea.

Comment: Besides a beefier power supply I would add a powered USB hub - wspwxially since a HDD can be pretty power hungry on  startup.

Comment: Thanks, this was a power related problem. It works well with a powered USB hub.

Answer (score 2):

Rasi pi works on minimum amount of power. Connect your USB drive to powered Hub & then connect the powered hub to the Rasi Pi. Also make sure you are supplying adequate amount of voltage to the Pi board.