# Max safe current and power requirements for Raspberry Pi 2 Model B?

Tags: usb, power, hard-drive

I have a few questions to ask. I have referred to many other similar questions, but couldn't get a straight forward answer to my questions.

Current situation: 
I just recently bought a Canakit Raspberry Pi 2 Kit. I want to use it as a media server and a file server (I am using one hard disk for each purpose). I have set up everything except that my hard disks are not getting enough power.

1. What is the maximum safe power (current and voltage) that I can provide my raspberry pi using a power adapter?
2. What is the power output by the USB ports on RPi and how to increase it. (I'm unable to power my hard disks through it. I want to connect 2 Hard disks)
3. What is the required power/current adapter for my requirements? (Simply said, what adapter should I use for this)

Comment: You WILL need a powered USB hub **unless the hard-drives have their own Power Supplies** - although the later models including the 2 B have an option to increase the power available through the USB ports - I have a hard time believing it would be enough fornot just one but two HDDs!

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is to use a powered USB hub to connect the drives to the Pi.

**TL;DR**

The Pi needs a 5 volt power supply. The Pi will only draw as much current as it needs so something between 1 and 2.5 amps should be fine. The one that came with your kit should be fine.

To change the amount of power supplied by the USB ports:

edit the `/boot/config.txt` set the `max_usb_current=1`

This will set the available current over USB to 1.2A (default is 600mA). For additional details see this [question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27708/is-setting-max-usb-current-1-to-give-more-power-to-usb-devices-a-bad-idea).

Also please note that shopping recommendations are [off-topic](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) per the site [FAQ](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: The max_usb_current=1 setting also seems to fail. Hard disk makes a sound indicating lack of current. 
So there is no way other than using a powered usb hub ?

Comment: @HarishR There are only so many ways of saying you need a powered hub for your drives.